# Power Pivot support in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, migration, powerpivot, powerbi

We have **SharePoint 2010** environment and we are using **Power Pivot** service for reporting and data source as SharePoint list.

Since now we are **migrating to SharePoint online** (Office365), So Could anyone suggest me What is best to use Power Pivot with SharePoint Online.

1. Is SharePoint Online supports Power Pivot?
2. Compatibility and support of Power Pivot with SharePoint Online?
3. Is it best way use Power Pivot on SharePoint Online also? or
   is there any better solutions present with SharePoint Online like PowerBI?
4. If PowerBI, then how we will gonna move my existing Power Pivot
   report to PowerBI?

Any information will be useful, so please comment your thoughts.

Comment: as far as i know, SharePoint Online does not support PowerPivot, 
if you want powerpivots you require power Bi with the enterprise gateway

Comment: Ok, will i able to move my existing Power Pivot report to PowerBI easily?

Comment: SharePoint Online now supports Power Pivot in Excel workbooks, as does One Drive. This is a fairly recent feature. I haven't tried it using a SharePoint List as a data source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerPivot is not available in SharePoint Online. The alternative would be Power BI or using PowerPivot for Excel only. If using PowerPivot for Excel, your users cannot open the Excel directly in SP Online, they need to open the Excel sheet in the client.

It is easy to move existing Power Pivot report to PowerBI, you can refer to below articles for more information:

https://sqldusty.com/2015/08/20/importing-a-power-pivot-model-power-view-into-power-bi/

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-import-excel-workbooks

Comment: Would it be possible to share the PowerShell code and explain how you automated the refresh please? Best regards,
Mo Oweis

Answer (score 0):

I use Excel Services Web Parts in SPO to host PowerPivot Workbooks currently (9-12-2018). PowerPivot work books also work just fine presented in Excel Online. It's your choice.

To refresh the PowerPivot data in the workbooks I have to use PowerShell and save to sync'd folder for the Document Library that holds the workbook.